# Identify if a value is greater or less than the previous value

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I am creating a scorecard that tracks a number of issues reported each week.

I am looking to add formatting that

- if the previous value is greater than the current value it should be highlighted in red
- and if the previous value is smaller than the current value it should be highlighted in green.

I have this setup in a table that lists the values each week.

[image: Screenshot of data i am trying to apply this to]

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you mock up some data?

Comment: Use conditional formatting

Comment: Could you please provide a sample? General, we could create 2 rules in Condition Formatting. Such as one is **=IF(B3>B2,TRUE**, format Green, another one is **=IF(B3<B2,TRUE)**, format Red. B3 represents current value, B2 represents previous value.

Comment: Hello I have added a screenshot of the data I am trying to apply this rule to

Answer (score 1):

What about when the current value is equal previous value? I classify it as green type.

Here I select the cells from B5:L5 to highlight, select Condition Formatting in Styles group > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format.

Enter "=IF(B5 Format, red (red for Fill, Font or others).

Do the same steps to create the second rule, enter"=IF(B5>=B4,TRUE)" > Format, green.

The following pictures show the Condition Formatting Rules Manager and the result.

[image]
[image]

When you need to apply rules to other cells, you could modify the range in Condition Formatting Rules Manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this in the code for the worksheet: it only changes the color between C2 and C100 but you can change the column and range in the code to suit.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Excel.Range)

Dim MyRnge As Range, c As Range
Set MyRnge = Range("$C$2:$C$100")

If target.Column = 3 Then
    For Each c In MyRnge
        If c.Value > c.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then c.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        If c.Value < c.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then c.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Next c
End If
End Sub
'------------------------------------ version 2
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim MyRnge As Range, c As Range
Set MyRnge = Range("$A$117:$H$118")

If Target = Range("$A$117") Then
    For Each c In MyRnge
        If c.Value > Target.Value Then c.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        If c.Value < Target.Value Then c.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Next c
End If
End Sub
'---------------version 3
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim MyRnge As Range, c As Range, mycell As Range
Set MyRnge = Range(Cells(5, 2), Cells(5, Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))

If Not Intersect(Target, MyRnge) Is Nothing Then
    For Each c In MyRnge
        If c.Value > c.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then c.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        If c.Value < c.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then c.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Next c
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer just wondering would this work if my values arent all in the same row they are in different columns? I have added a screenshot to give you more visibility.

Comment: going through all cells at each change is just overkill. For a bigger worksheet it'd completely ruin performance.

Comment: Cheers Mate, I agree... but what would the solution be? And how big is the sheet going to be, for a few thousand cells I doubt this would affect performance, could put it on a button or make it double click or linked to a value in a cell I guess.

Comment: @JustinDoward  add some screen shot ,,, used by the OP will make it clear that how far the code is working or not !!

Comment: @RajeshS I am not 100% sure now what the requirements are, Justin C the code will now only update on change of A117 cell, all other values are compared to this cell. Let me know if this was not what you are after.

Comment: @JustinDoward,, your code is only two rows 117 & 118,, if I add new rows below does't performs as expected,, please check the code because new rows are always possible to be added !!

Comment: Justin C, I think version 3 is what you are after. It now has a volatile range for S5 to any number of columns. @RajeshS I am not sure making the range volatile for rows would be useful based on Justin's data, however I will wait for his response. Thank you for the pointer though, it did prompt me to make the column range volatile.